# fwrite() is faster if unlink() the file in prior than truncate it

Tags: c, linux

I want to run a simple test of disk performance on a rhel 6 platform. It's just to write down 1G bytes to the disk. I found if the file was unlinked first, it would be much faster than it was truncated. It was about 1.5s versus 15s.

Why? I thought unlink() the last hard link will truncate the file to 0 and delete the inode. Why fwrites were faster with unlink() than truncate?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2) {
        return -1;
    }

    char buf[1024];

    srand(time(0));

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 1024; ++i) {
        buf[i] = rand();
    }

    /* unlink(argv[1]); */
    FILE* fp = fopen(argv[1], "wb+");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("fopen");
        return -1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 1024 * 1024; ++i) {
        if (fwrite(buf, 1024, 1, fp) != 1) {
            perror("fwrite");
            return -1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Deleting a file may appear faster than truncating it when you have enough free space on the disk and the file system can delete files and reclaim their space lazily. It can just mark the inode as being deleted and delete the file in the background or at a later time and create a new inode almost instantly, ready for new writes.

Comment: Alexey, thanks for your answer. I had the same thought about this though I'm not sure. But still I don't understand why truncate is not implemented like this. If a file is truncated to zero, why not move the truncated blocks to a new inode and keep the current inode clean for next write?

Comment: I don't know for sure. Really, the answer to your question depends on the implementation of the file system. You may want to research this further, see file system documentation or source code and look up performance discussions on the web.

Comment: @Zhongzhi "why not move the truncated blocks to a new inode" -- What new inode? Allocating an inode just to make your program faster at the expense of the rest of the system is a lousy idea and a pointless complication of the FS code. That's quite different from the fact that block reclamation upon deleting the last link to a file isn't charged to the deleter because the blocks are reclaimed asynchronously.